# Login and Sessions with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I am having a problem with my login script that I am working with, I added an password decryption part because i encrypted password using the password_hasf function. Since I am new to php, I am having hard time solving this one. I hope you guys could help me with this one. Thanks!

Here are the login codes:

```
*<?php

session_start();


include "../config.php"; 


$username = $_REQUEST['username']; 

$password = $_REQUEST['password']; 

// dehashing

$sql = "SELECT COUNT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='$username' AND 
password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$pwd_hash = $row['password'];

$hash = password_verify($row,$pwd_hash);


if($hash == FALSE){

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Sorry! Cannot login.'); 
</script>";

} else {  


$sql = "SELECT uid,username,password,activated FROM tbl_user WHERE 
username='$username' AND password='$password'";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


$login_variables = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$_SESSION['login_username']=$login_variables['username'];


if(isset($_SESSION['login_username'])){

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('You are now logged in as ". 
$_SESSION['login_username'] ."'); document.location.href='../index.php' 
</script>";

} else {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Sorry! Cannot login.'); 
document.location.href='javascript: history.go(-1)'</script>";

exit;

}

}

?>
```

And my index:

```
*<?php
header("location: list.php");
?>*
```

And my list:

```
*<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_username']))
{
    header("location: ../login.php");
    exit;
}
?>*
```

And on the list is some html tables and stuff.

Comment: stop now before your hacked

Comment: Please stop storing plain text passwords in your database and don't be [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Hash passwords properly using PHP's Password Hashing API!

Comment: Yup I am researching on password encrypting

Comment: Dont store the password in the session!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have a 'sess_username' and the rest are 'sees_username'. That would stop it from working!

Comment: I fix it and it is already working. A typo error after all. Thanks

Comment: please help me with password_verify function. it's not working

Comment: It looks like your SQL is just counting rows, but that gives you the value of $row . Is that right? $row needs to be the actual password in `password_verify` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
*<?php
  session_start();
  include "../config.php"; //database connection
  $username = $_REQUEST['username']; //information from login form
  $password = $_REQUEST['password']; //information from login form
  $sql = "SELECT uid,username,password FROM tbl_user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $login_variables = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $_SESSION = array(
    'sess_username' => $login_variables['username'],
    'sees_password' => $login_variables['password']
  );
  if(isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && isset($_SESSION['sees_password']))
  {
    header ("location: ../index.php");
  } 
  else
  {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Sorry! Cannot login.'); document.location.href='javascript: history.go(-1)'</script>";

}
?>*
```

and

```
*<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && ($_SESSION['sees_password']))
  {
    header("location: ../login.php");
  }
?>*
```

Comment: I edited also the first set of codes. Tried it both?

Comment: Please vote my answer so this question be considered as SOLVED. Thanks!

Comment: please help me with password_verify function. it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You dont tell us what problems that you are having.
Apart from the code opening yourself up for sql injection you could try and change

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'sess_username' => $login_variables['username'],
    'sees_password' => $login_variables['password']
);
```

to

```
$_SESSION['sess_username']=$login_variables['username'];
$_SESSION['sees_password']=$login_variables['password'];
```

EDIT : 
if you are storing your login details like:

```
INSERT INTO table (username,password) VALUES ('{$user}',password_hash($pass) );
```

then you can use

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='$username' AND 
password='".password_hash($password)."'";
```

to retrieve the relevant information

Comment: I cannot login using those codes above that I wrote. It just always echo the javascript even if I am writing the write username and passoword from the users table that i created in my database

Comment: please help me with password_verify function. it's not working

Comment: it still doesnt work. I use password_bcrypt as my algorithm in hashing passwords

Answer (score 0):

The site's vulnerability and password confidentiality, you improve if after the login is working.

Login Code:

```
*<?php
  session_start();
  include "../config.php"; //database connection
  $username = $_REQUEST['username']; //information from login form
  $password = $_REQUEST['password']; //information from login form
  $sql = "SELECT uid,username,password FROM tbl_user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $login_variables = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $login_variables['username'];
  $_SESSION['sess_password'] = $login_variables['password'];

  if(isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && isset($_SESSION['sess_password']))
  {
    header ("location: ../index.php");
  } 
  else
  {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Sorry! Cannot login.'); document.location.href='javascript: history.go(-1)'</script>";

}
?>*
```

Index:

```
*<?php
   header("location: list.php");
?>*
```

List:

```
*<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && ($_SESSION['sess_password']))
  {
    header("location: ../login.php");
    exit;
  }
?>*
```

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you getting redirected back and stuck in loop?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sees_username']) && ($_SESSION['sees_password']))
```

?

change to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sees_username']) && !isset($_SESSION['sees_password']))
```

in your index.php

as one will check if the password exists and the other will check if the username is not set

so in your code it would redirect to login as condition 2 in your if stamenent is met

Comment: yup i am just redirected back because of this error. thanks! I just removed the codes that will check the password so that i could login.

Comment: i think you can still check if password is no set  just correct the spelling

Comment: please help me with password_verify function. it's not working